# Windows 8 Snap on desktop not working

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying Windows 8 and I want to test the new snap feature where you can have two metro apps side-by-side.

However, it doesn't seem to work. I place my cursor on top of the screen, and drag left or right, but all it does is move the current app around, and when I release my mouse it always goes back to the original, single-app view.

So how do I properly use this feature on a desktop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to drag the app to the left or right until you see a vertical dividing line appear in the background. Once you see that, you can release the mouse button and it should be snapped to that side of the display.

However, this feature requires **at least a 1366x768 screen resolution**. If your screen's resolution is smaller than this, Windows disables the ability to snap metro apps. The recommended way to get it is to increase your screen resolution in order to take advantage of this feature.

However, allegedly you can do a quick modification in the Windows Registry to force it to be enabled, regardless of your resolution. As always, **proceed with caution**, and keep backups, since you can break your Windows installation if you change the wrong thing. Also, this is not intended behavior, so your apps may not display properly with this change. If you want to try this, though, I put the steps, below.

*Note: I haven't tried this, myself. These steps come from [this guide](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-force-enable-windows-8-snap-feature-in-low-screen-resolutions/).*

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key combination to launch *Run* dialog box then type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It'll open the *Registry Editor*. Go to following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\`
2. Under `ImmersiveShell` key, create a new key `AppPositioner`.
3. Now select newly created key `AppPositioner` and in right-side pane, create a new DWORD `AlwaysEnableLSSnapping` and set its value to `1`.
4. Restart your system or restart Explorer and you should be able to snap your Metro apps to the sides of your screen.

That's it! There's also a registry trick at that link which explains how to trick Windows 8 into thinking you have that screen resolution, even if it's lower. It apparently causes Windows to downsample the App, effectively scaling it to your screen size. You may (or may not) need to take advantage of that trick as well. Caution applies here, just as above, as you're editing the Registry.

Comment: I never see any such line, even if I drag to the far-left/right of the display...

Comment: It may be a screen resolution issue, then... I'll update the answer.

Comment: I'm running it in a VM on a Mac if that changes anything

Comment: My resolution is 1280x1024 so it should work even without the registry key. But it didn't so I tried adding it. Still no luck however...

Comment: IIRC Modern UI itself requires 1024x768, but Snap requires 1366x768.

Comment: Thanks, that might be the issue, then. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @houbysoft I updated my answer with the new information. It might explain why your resolution wasn't large enough... you still didn't meet the minimum horizontal resolution.

Comment: @Bob: thanks that was it. Changed resolution to 1366x768 and it started working :)

Comment: too bad, they removed the hack in the RTM...

Comment: Here's the link for the hack mentioned at the end in case anyone finds it useful: http://liliputing.com/2011/09/how-to-enable-windows-8-metro-style-apps-on-an-older-netbook.html (and if it still works)

Comment: Unfortunately, this hack does not seem to be working using RTM version

Answer (score 16):

**[Multitasking with snap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx#snap_ux) is only available on displays with a resolution of 1366x768 and above**.

Standard resolution for a non-widescreen 19" monitor is 1280x1024 which is not wide enough to enable this feature.

It is the number of pixels available for the width that is most important here, (1280px vs 1366px required).
The snap view is a fixed 320px wide and the minimum resolution for a 'non-snapped' Windows 8 application is 1024x768.

> 320px + 1024px + 22px for the divider = 1366px

[image: Snapped app resolution]

Comment: Very nice analysis!