# Why can't I snap or dock two Windows 8 apps side-by-side on my 19" monitor

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 Snap on desktop not working](https://superuser.com/questions/494288/windows-8-snap-on-desktop-not-working)

I have a dual monitor setup with a Dell 19" monitor as my main display and my laptop screen as my secondary display.

I am running Windows 8 and have been experimenting with the snap/dock feature of Metro style apps to tile two apps vertically on one screen. This works just fine on my laptop display, but the same apps wont 'snap' on my Dell monitor.

How can I enable this functionality on both displays?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.